# How to keep text in an x,y coordinate in html?

Tags: html, text, position, coordinates

I am trying to put text in an x,y coordinate window on my website page through HTML, how do I do it? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
           <head>
                  <center><h1>Hello</h1></center>
           </head>
     </html>
```

Currently, the code will have "Hello" in the center of the window, but I want it at (100,100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:fixed`, `top:100px` and `left:100px`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    h1 {
      position: fixed;
      top: 100px;
      left: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried running the program, but do I keep the first code snippet in a separate file? Here is my current code: 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
           <head>
                  h1{position:fixed;top:100px;left:100px;}
                  <h1>Hello</h1>
           </head>
           <body>

     </html>`

Comment: It works when I run the StackOverflow "run code snippet" button, but it doesn't work when I do it on my local disk.

Comment: @ViperStream I've edited my answer. You can just copy and paste it over to your local disk now.